# 'gem install bundle' get something wrong

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos

I want to install ruby.
My OS is centos5.5.
When I `gem install bundle` 
this get something wrong

> ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
>       no such file to load -- zlib
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
>       uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

I try `yum install zlib`, but it prompts

> Package zlib-1.2.3-4.el5.i386 already installed and latest version

I have searched this error, but I still can not solve this problem.
I found `/usr/local/rvm/src` has `zlib-1.2.6`.
I try into `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318/ext/zlib` and compile it
`ruby extconf.rb`
But I got this infomations:

> ```
> checking for deflateReset() in -ltrue... no
> checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... no
> checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib1... no
> checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... no
> checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... no
> ```

So how can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: try this `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems rvm is unable to find zlib. Try reinstalling ruby by first installing zlib for the rvm.

```
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm remove 1.9.2 
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Comment: Try this 
yum install zlib zlib-devel


cd /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318/ext/zlib


ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install

Comment: Thanks, It gets solved.   But I also have tried this before, It cannot works. Now It works. I do not konw why.