# What can I do to resolve this error when trying to install bundler?

Tags: rubygems, installation, rvm, bundler

I am trying to run this command

```
gem install bundler
```

but I am always getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

What can I do about this? I already tried this (as pointed out here ['gem install bundle' get something wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070830/gem-install-bundle-get-something-wrong)):

```
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm remove 2.0.0 
rvm install 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's a known issue - rubygems 2.0.0 requires openssl, run this:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --autolibs=3
```

Comment: hey i just ran into this problem. Maybe you have an idea... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393462/what-can-i-do-about-a-bundlergemfilenotfound-error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin, try to reinstall the ruby packages using the installer.
Even if they are the same version.