# Unable to install any Ruby gems - undefined method `invoke_with_build_args`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed Ruby 2.1 from rubyinstaller.org on my Windows 7 system.

While trying to install any gem, I am facing the following error:

```
C:\Ruby21>gem install compass
ERROR:  Loading command: install (Win32::Registry::Error)
    The system cannot find the file specified.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I've no clue what's wrong.

Comment: Try opening the thing that is 30 years behind the unix shell aka Commandprompt with admin access. Then rerun your command as admin.

Comment: @auL5agoi Still the same error! :/

Comment: what is the full trace?  run `gem install compass --trace`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Weird. It returns the exact same error. No trace.

Comment: Well, can advice only use other shell , Cygwin or mingw or etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do to resolve this error when trying to install bundler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392752/what-can-i-do-to-resolve-this-error-when-trying-to-install-bundler)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall again the ruby package using cygwin installer. Even if they are the same version.