# Rbenv image not found but version is installed

Tags: ruby, rbenv

When I run `rbenv versions` I get:

```
  system
  2.3.1
  2.4.1
  2.4.2
  2.4.3
  2.5.0
  2.5.1
* 2.6.3 (set by /Users/me/Documents/procore/.ruby-version)
```

But when I run `gem install bundler` I get:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: It looks like it's telling you that it can't find openssl rather than a specific ruby version. This Q+A is using Ruby Version Manager but may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392752/what-can-i-do-to-resolve-this-error-when-trying-to-install-bundler

Comment: After an operating system upgrade you may need to rebuild or reinstall any versions of Ruby you use as the shared libraries linked against may have changed.

Comment: @tadman is correct; OS changes can update libraries and any native code previously compiled can suddenly break so recompiling is necessary. `gem pristine` might help. See `gem help pristine` for more information.